# Shuffle in Python

Tags: python, random, shuffle

Is there a straightforward way to RETURN a shuffled array in Python rather than shuffling it in place?

e.g., instead of

```
x = [array]
random.shuffle(x)
```

I'm looking for something like

```
y = shuffle(x)
```

which maintains x.

Note, I am not looking for a function, not something like:

```
x=[array]
y=x
random.shuffle(x)
```

Comment: Discussed in a post on python-ideas in 2009, discouraged because you can write `y = sorted(yourList, key=lambda x: random.random())`. See: http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2009-March/003661.html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`sorted` with a `key` function that returns a random value:

```
import random
sorted(l, key=lambda *args: random.random())
```

Or

```
import os
sorted(l, key=os.urandom)
```

Comment: This is short, but scales as O(n log n), whereas the copy of the input list followed by `random.shuffle` is O(n).  Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuffling#Shuffling_algorithms

Comment: Doing the latter on an array of strings resulted in: sorted(a, key=os.urandom) TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer. Doing the former worked as expected. I wonder if there's a way to do the latter on a array of strings?

Comment: Also consider that this may not sort fairly. I would expect there will be a bias for "sorted" items to stay close to their original location in the list, whereas using `random.shuffle` should have no bias based on the original list's order.

Answer (score 13):

It would be pretty simple to implement your own using `random`.  I would write it as follows:

```
def shuffle(l):
    l2 = l[:]           #copy l into l2
    random.shuffle(l2)  #shuffle l2
    return l2           #return shuffled l2
```

Comment: +1: this is O(n), whereas the `sorted(…, key=os.urandom)` is in O(n log n).

Answer (score 8):

Just write your own.

```
import random

def shuffle(x):
    x = list(x)
    random.shuffle(x)
    return x

x = range(10)
y = shuffle(x)
print x # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
print y # [2, 5, 0, 4, 9, 3, 6, 1, 7, 8]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to save effort-- having to include this in all of the programs that I write is more effort than just using the original formulation.

Comment: You want me to magically add something to the Python standard library instead? Why do you need shuffled *copies* in "all of the programs" that you write anyway?

Comment: I don't want you to magically do anything, I was just asking if such a function existed in a standard library. I don't need copies per se, I'd like to define an array like x=shuffled([1 2 3 4 5]) rather than having to define it over two lines.

Comment: @Jeff, there is nothing wrong with creating your own libraries to be used across your programs. And if (for some reason) you were writing single file programs then you can just copy the text in as you are creating your new program, or turn it into a snippet within your favourite text editor ... so +1

Comment: @avasopht absolutely nothing wrong with that, it just wasn't what i was looking for

Answer (score 5):

There is no function you are looking for. Just copy a list.

Answer (score 2):

You could use numpy.random.permutation for either a list or array, but is the right function if you have a numpy array already. For lists with mixed types, converting to a numpy array will do type conversions.

```
import numpy as np
my_list = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 42]
print list(np.random.permutation(my_list))
# ['bar', 'baz', '42', 'foo']
```

Comment: This is the best solution to this question!

Answer (score 0):

Using this as a demo elsewhere so thought it may be worth sharing:

```
import random

x = shuffleThis(x)


def shuffleThis(y):
    random.shuffle(y)
    return(y)
#end of Shuffle Function
```

Hope this is useful.